# SPI vs HDMI power consumption

Tags: hdmi, spi

I'm using a Pi Zero in a portable project and wondered if there were any power savings to be made by using an SPI display over a HDMI one or vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

I think MUCH larger difference will be in how much power the display uses based on its size and type rather then the control signals you are feeding it with. An  20 inch LCD monitor over HDMI is going to draw way more power then a small SPI screen.   And if you are working with the same size/type of screen, I think the large draw for the screen will make the small difference in power consumption between the two types of communication a moot point.

Comment: Assume an identical display/work load in both cases. My question is only very generally whether there is a noticeable power saving to be made using either interface.

Comment: I'd assume HDMI do consume lower power as the CPU does not have to generate SPI Signals all the time the GPU is much better in that regards. But I don't have any evidence for that.